# Match the font scale

Tags: fonts

How to much the font to this ?

[image]

My current font

[image]

I don't get if this is the spacing of the font.

```
      \begin{center}
  \SetTblrInner{rowsep=0.1pt,colsep=10pt}
      \begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines,
                  colspec = {c X[c] X[c] X[c]},
                  rowspec = {Q[gray9]},
                  row{1}  = {font=\fontsize{7pt}{7pt}\fontfamily{phv}\bfseries, t},
                  row{2-7}  = {font=\fontsize{7pt}{7pt}, l},
                  vspan   = even
                  }
  No. & In Charage    & Operation Description & Remarks       \\
  1  & Administrator
                      & Adding Operation Tenants        & Collumn 4     \\
  2  &               & Collumn 3             & Collumn 4     \\
  3 & Collumn 2      & Collumn 3             & Collumn 4     \\
  4 & Collumn 2      & Collumn 3             & Collumn 4     \\ 
  5 & Collumn 2      & Collumn 3             & Collumn 4     \\
  6 & Collumn 2      & Collumn 3             & Collumn 4     \\
      \end{tblr}
  \end{center}
```

Comment: I'm having some trouble understanding what question you're asking, or what you want done. The main reason the spacing in the second picture is different than in the first is that the "Adding Operation Tenants" is wrapped to be two lines in the second picture. To fix that, you'd need to change the column width, or use a smaller or narrower font. `\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}` would give you a more compact font matching the first image and might fix the problem with the wrapping for "Adding Operation Tenants". But I'm not sure I understand your question. "Column" only has one l, btw.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion just thinking if it's the font scale.